# Customizing the language-guessing algorithm in Django

Tags: python, django, django-multilingual

I'm developing a multilingual Django website. It has two languages, English and Hebrew. I want the default language for every first-time visitor to be Hebrew, regardless of what his browser's `Accept-Language` is.

Of course, if he changes language to English (and thus gets the language cookie or the key in the session), it should remain at English.

I think I can program this algorithm myself, but where do I "plug it in"? How do I make my project use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't have to override anything. You can just check on the first page, (or maybe every page) if the user already has a language cookie and otherwise redirect him to the set_language redirect view. In that way you could force the language to Hebrew.

If the user decides to change back to English, he can do it very easily.

Comment: This inspired me to create a little middleware that did exactly what you said. (I did it as a middleware so it will automatically apply to all pages.)

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/#topics-i18n

Then read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/internationalization/#topics-i18n-internationalization

> Each RequestContext has access to
>   three translation-specific variables:
>
> LANGUAGES is a list of tuples in which
>   the first element is the language code
>   and the second is the language name
>   (translated into the currently active
>   locale).
>
> LANGUAGE_CODE is the current
>   user's preferred language, as a
>   string. Example: en-us. (See How
>   Django discovers language preference.)
>
> LANGUAGE_BIDI is the current locale's
>   direction. If True, it's a
>   right-to-left language, e.g.: Hebrew,
>   Arabic. If False it's a left-to-right
>   language, e.g.: English, French,
>   German etc.
>
> If you don't use the
>   RequestContext extension, you can get
>   those values with three tags:

Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: I read your link before, and also this one: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/deployment/

But I didn't see anything about how to customize the algorithm.

Comment: @cool-RR: "customize the algorithm"?  Do you mean override the settings found in the Request?  Are you asking about how to use the "Each RequestContext has access to three translation-specific variables"?

Comment: No. I'm talking about the algorithm by which Django determines the user's language. Check out the function `django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request`. I want to override it somehow.

Comment: @cool-RR: Actually, I don't think you do.  I think you want to customize the language in which you reply, based on the "get_language_from_request" plus your application-specific settings.

Comment: I'm not seeing how your idea would work. HOW am I supposed to do this?

Comment: @cool-RR: Your view function provides the language settings to the template for rendering.  Your view function looks at session state, user profile and get_language_from_request to decide which language setting to provide to the template.